# Not given the option for kids to move

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I just built the lake view manor and it is fully furnished. I have 2 children's beds and chests. My husband gave me the option to move to the new location, but my kids don't have that option. Is there something else I need?

Comment: I *think* your kids will move along with your hubby and you don't need to ask them specifically.

Answer (score 3):

When you tell your spouse to move, they will automatically move the kids as well.  I've done this in game many times.

Comment: Thanks...yea my game had a glitch but it fixed itself. I asked my husband to go and he went, but my kids remained in whiterun...but when I restarted the game and fast traveled to the Lakeview Manor they were there...so the glitch worked itself out. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the **Unofficial Hearthfire Patch** to fix the bug. Sometimes you can tell your spouse to move to another place and the kid go with them, but as you said the kids were staying in Whiterun while your spouse was in Lakeview Manor.